# Wordpress Category control links disappeared

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a wordpress theme. In the category listings of posts (or any other post type) I can't see links like "edit", "quick edit" or "delete".

I have many hooks related with post types I checked them but didn't find anything which may remove those control links.

What do you think? Am I doing something wrong related with hooks?
Thanks

[image: WP Category Listing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the answer, the problem is in the admin.css! 
I also used a class named .column-description in my admin.css which changes the size of that part and links are hidden!